# Reason for Scala list methods using mutables internally

Tags: scala, immutability, purely-functional

Scala talks all about immutability and all the operations performed on the lists create another collection. But when going through the internal implementation of List methods, many of them use mutables i.e vars to perform the operation.

For example, the reverse function of lists

```
  override def reverse: List[A] = {
    var result: List[A] = Nil
    var these = this
    while (!these.isEmpty) {
      result = these.head :: result
      these = these.tail
    }
    result
  }
```

or even the foldLeft functions

```
  def foldLeft[B](z: B)(@deprecatedName('f) op: (B, A) => B): B = {
    var acc = z
    var these = this
    while (!these.isEmpty) {
      acc = op(acc, these.head)
      these = these.tail
    }
    acc
  }
```

and many more.

Please let me know if I am missing out on some concept somewhere because this question of using mutables internally is baffling me for quite some time now. 
Please let me know the reason for using mutables and not following a purely functional approach. Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Performance could be a reason. Creating objects is expensive.

Comment: They could have used tail recursion if performance would be an issue. I guess there is something more to this than just performance.

Answer (score 0):

if you see the implementation of the reverse function. It uses var result just because it need to assign the new list again and again. If you closely look into the statement `these.head :: result` it's a prepand operation which is `O(1)` operation w.r.t time complexity. That's how we neither compromising with efficiency nor immutability.

so that's how it is maintaing the immutability by creating a new list over and over we are not changing the same instance of the list and returning the result which is of type `List[A]`.

Actually performance will be an issue if we use either recursion or tail recursion or append operation. This is a myth that recursion is faster or more efficient than the normal processing it has nothing to do with efficiency more over recursion has a draw back of having stackOverflow error.
If we talk about the append operation then it is `O(n)` peration w.r.t time complexity.
If we talk about tail recursion then it is memorty efficient recursion not the time efficient, it just help us avoiding the StackOverFlow error.

I have written the same reverse fucntion with tailRec and the normal one and i ran my program saveral times and 90% the var version of the code took much lesser time than the recursive one on such small input. I think the use of var is just becuase of the performance.

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

object Solution extends App {

  val a = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2,
    3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3,
    4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4,
    5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4,
    5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

  def reverse[A](l: List[A]): List[A] = {
    @tailrec
    def reverseTailrec[A](list: List[A], ans: List[A]): List[A] = {
      if (list == Nil) return ans

      reverseTailrec(list.tail, list.head :: ans)
    }

    reverseTailrec(l, Nil)
  }

  val t1 = System.currentTimeMillis()
  val answer = reverse(a)
  val t2 = System.currentTimeMillis()

  println(s"${t2 - t1} : mSec")


  def reverseSimple[A](list: List[A]): List[A] = {
    var result: List[A] = Nil
    var these = list
    while (these.nonEmpty) {
      result = these.head :: result
      these = these.tail
    }
    result
  }

  val t3 = System.currentTimeMillis()
  val res = reverseSimple(a)
  val t4 = System.currentTimeMillis()

  println(s"${t4 - t3} : mSec")
}
```

sample output:

1. run

   4 : mSec recursive
   1 : mSec non-recursive
   2.run

   7 : mSec recursive
   1 : mSec non-recursive
   3.run

   8 : mSec recursive
   2 : mSec non-recursive
   4.run

   4 : mSec recursive
   1 : mSec non-recursive
   5.run

   4 : mSec recursive
   2 : mSec non-recursive

I think that's helpful.

Answer (score -1):

When you're working on a program that'll be used by just your team or two, you choose readability, safety (which immutability helps with), and speed of development.
Scala best practices are meant for them.

However, when you're building a library that'll be used by a lot of users (say > 10, let alone hundreds of thousands), the most important feature is performance.

If benchmark tests show that a new implementation is much faster (without it being so esoteric/ugly that it hampers maintenance), the right thing to do is to choose the new implementation.

And benchmark tests have repeatedly shown that mutable solutions when no locking is involved is almost always faster and more memory efficient than immutable solutions.

Answer (score -3):

The principle of using immutable struct is to prevent locks between threads. You do not need to lock it when using it, because it is read-only, no other thread can modify it when the thread is reading.

All vars used in the functions are local variable, their references can't be shared between thread, so it is totally fine to use variable here.